# What are SDL's additional file dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sdl

What additional dependencies do I have to add to use SDL in Visual C++ 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You need the folder containing headers (stuff like SDL.h for compiling), the folder containing libraries (stuff like SDL.lib for linking), and the DLLs (stuff like SDL.dll for running).